# Joining list of dataframes in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to speed up the loop, in which consecutive dataframes are joined with the first one with the first column as key. Dataframes are produced by a function `my_function`. First column is named `:REF`. Consecutive Dataframes could be shorter that first one, thus I cannot directly assign to DF column, as I would do in pandas.

```
base_df = my_function(elem1)

for elem in elems[2:end]
    tmp = my_function(elem)
    base_df = join(base_df, tmp, on=:REF, kind=:left)
end
```

Is there any way to join list of dataframes into one?
Thanks,

PS: DataFrames are of different types: String, Int, Float64.

**Upd.** So, example DataFrames:

```
df1 = DataFrame(REF = 1:5, D1=rand(5))
df2 = DataFrame(REF = 1:3, D1=rand(3))
df3 = DataFrame(REF = 1:4, D1=rand(4))
```

What I looking for it to combine those three (or more) into single DataFrame at once. Note the row count differencies.

**Upd2.** Sorry, it should have been diffent columns on df1, df2 and df3 (D1, D2 and D3). Here is the correct setup of DFs

```
df1 = DataFrame(REF = 1:5, D1=rand(5))
df2 = DataFrame(REF = 1:3, D2=rand(3))
df3 = DataFrame(REF = 1:4, D3=rand(4))
```

Comment: Be useful if you could give an example of a couple of dataframes that are of the same type as what you are trying to use so someone can copy and paste your code :)

Comment: @AlexanderMorley Example code added, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach that assumes you want a left join (as in your question - if you need another type of join it should be simple to adjust it). The difference from Dan Getz solution is that it does not use `DataVector` but operates on arrays allowing `missing` (you can check the difference by running `showcols` on resulting `DataFrame`; the benefit is that it will be more efficient to work with such data later as we will know their types):

```
function joiner(ref_left, ref_right, val_right)
    x = DataFrames.similar_missing(val_right, length(ref_left))
    j = 1
    for i in 1:length(ref_left)
        while ref_left[i] > ref_right[j]
            j += 1
            j > length(ref_right) && return x
        end
        if ref_left[i] == ref_right[j]
            x[i] = val_right[j]
        end
    end
    return x
end

function left_join_sorted(elems::Vector{DataFrame}, on::Symbol)
    # we perform left join to base_df
    # the columns of elems[1] will be reused, use deepcopy if you want fresh columns
    base_df = copy(elems[1])
    ref_left = base_df[:REF]
    for i in 2:length(elems)
        df = elems[i]
        ref_right = df[:REF]
        for n in names(df)
            if n != on
                # this assumes that column names in all data frames except on are unique, otherwise they will be overwritten
                # we perform left join to the first DataFrame in elems
                base_df[n] = joiner(ref_left, ref_right, df[n])
            end
        end
    end
    base_df
end
```

Here is an example of usage:

```
julia> left_join_sorted([df1, df2, df3], :REF)
5×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ REF │ D1       │ D2        │ D3       │
├─────┼─────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 1   │ 0.133361 │ 0.179822  │ 0.200842 │
│ 2   │ 2   │ 0.548581 │ 0.836018  │ 0.906814 │
│ 3   │ 3   │ 0.304062 │ 0.0797432 │ 0.946639 │
│ 4   │ 4   │ 0.755515 │ missing   │ 0.519437 │
│ 5   │ 5   │ 0.571302 │ missing   │ missing  │
```

As a side benefit my benchmarks show that this is ~20x faster than using `DataVector` (if you want a further speedup use `@inbounds` but probably the benefits are not worth the risks).

EDIT: fixed condition in `joiner` loop.

Comment: Thank you. it turns out, it cannot work with Float indexes

Comment: I fixed a bug in the code - it should work with index of any type now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to setup the answer, suppose:

```
df1 = DataFrame(REF = 1:5, D1=rand(5))
df2 = DataFrame(REF = 1:3, D1=rand(3))
df3 = DataFrame(REF = 1:4, D1=rand(4))

elems = [df1, df2, df3]
my_function = identity
```

Now the code to generate the big DataFrame:

```
dfs = my_function.(elems)
base_df = DataFrame(Dict([f=>vcat(getindex.(dfs,f)...) for f in names(dfs[1])]...))
```

Giving something like:

```
12×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ D1         │ REF │
├─────┼────────────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 0.664144   │ 1   │
│ 2   │ 0.119155   │ 2   │
│ 3   │ 0.471053   │ 3   │
│ 4   │ 0.547811   │ 4   │
│ 5   │ 0.600263   │ 5   │
│ 6   │ 0.21306    │ 1   │
│ 7   │ 0.985412   │ 2   │
│ 8   │ 0.886738   │ 3   │
│ 9   │ 0.00926173 │ 1   │
│ 10  │ 0.701962   │ 2   │
│ 11  │ 0.328322   │ 3   │
│ 12  │ 0.753062   │ 4   │
```

This approach reduces the memory used from quadratic-ish to linear-ish (and performance improves inline with memory reduction)

**UPDATE**

As new details came to light (and my understanding of the question improved), here is code to better generate the desired `base_df`:

```
df1 = DataFrame(REF = 1:5, D1=rand(5))
df2 = DataFrame(REF = 1:3, D2=rand(3))
df3 = DataFrame(REF = 1:4, D3=rand(4))
elems = [df1, df2, df3]

cols = [(i,f) for (i,t) in enumerate(elems) for f in names(t) if !(f == :REF)]
rows = union(getindex.(elems,:REF)...)
ref2row = Dict(v=>i for (i,v) in enumerate(rows))

pre_df = Dict{Symbol,DataVector{Any}}([c[2]=>DataArray(eltype(elems[c[1]][c[2]]),
 length(rows)) for c in cols])

foreach(tpl -> pre_df[tpl[3][1]][ref2row[tpl[2]]] = tpl[3][2],
 [(i,r[:REF],v) 
  for (i,t) in enumerate(elems) 
  for r in eachrow(t) 
  for v in r if v[1] != :REF
 ])

pre_df[:REF] = [ref2row[i] for i=1:length(rows)]

base_df = DataFrame(pre_df)
```

Giving:

```
5×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ D1       │ D2       │ D3        │ REF │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 0.93479  │ 0.582954 │ 0.133983  │ 1   │
│ 2   │ 0.472456 │ 0.992173 │ 0.32442   │ 2   │
│ 3   │ 0.365478 │ 0.117772 │ 0.62522   │ 3   │
│ 4   │ 0.976192 │ NA       │ 0.0861988 │ 4   │
│ 5   │ 0.76358  │ NA       │ NA        │ 5   │
```

Comment: And if you want to get separate columns you can use `unstack`. The only problem is that in this approach you do not get left join as all `REF` values from other `DataFrame`s will be added - even those that are not present in the first `DataFrame`.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been different columns (D1, D2 and D3) on df1, df2 and df3, accidentally named them all as D1.

Comment: @crayxt then if you want maximum efficiency there are the following questions that affect the most efficient solution: 1) is `base_df` sorted on `REF`, 2) are the other `df...` data frames sorted on `REF`, 3) are `REF` values in `base_df` unique, 2) are `REF` values in other `df...` unique.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Hi, thanks for your help. Answer is Yes to all 4 questions.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect my new understanding of the question

Comment: Thank you @DanGetz